# Solve ODE: $y''=e^y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> Solve ODE: $y''=e^y$

Here we don't have $x$ $\Rightarrow$ let $y'=p(y)\Rightarrow y''=pp'(y)$
We get: $pp'=e^y$
$$p\,dp=e^y\,dy \\
{p^2\over2}=e^y+C\\
y'=\sqrt{2e^y+2C}\\
{dy\over\sqrt{2}\sqrt{e^y+C}}=dx$$
That's where I am stuck and don't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{e^y+C}}=\left| t=\sqrt{e^y+C} \atop dt=\frac{e^y\,dy}{2\sqrt{e^y+C}}\right|=
2\int \frac{dt}{e^y}=2\int \frac{dt}{t^2-C}
$$